# Is $S$ a countable set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S=\{(x,y)|x^{2}+y^{2}=\frac{1}{n^{2}} \}$, where $n\in  \mathbb{N}$ and either $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ or $y\in \mathbb{Q}$. Then which of the following are correct?

(a) S is a finite non-empty set

(b)S is countable

(c) S is uncountable

(d) S is empty

This set $S$ is given as countable. But I am not getting, how they get so.

Suppose we take $x$ as rational.
$$\begin{aligned}y^{2}&=\frac{1}{n^{2}}-x^{2}\\&=\frac{1-n^{2}x^{2}}{n^{2}}\\y&=\sqrt{\frac{1-n^{2}x^{2}}{n^{2}}}\\&=\frac{\sqrt{1-n^{2}x^{2}}}{n}\end{aligned}$$

Here if $\sqrt{1-n^{2}x^{2}}$, is also a rational, then $y$ will also be rational and we can say $S\subset \mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$. So since $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ is countable, $S$ will also be countable.

But how will I be sure that $\sqrt{1-n^{2}x^{2}}\in \mathbb{Q}$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Pick $y=0$. What do you observe? Can you find a bunch of solutions?

Comment: You don't need $y$ to be rational (it generally won't be).  Given a fixed $x$ and $n$, you find at most two associated values for $y$.  Can you do something with that?

Comment: For each $x\in \mathbb Q$, your argument shows that $y$ can have atmost $2$ values. What can you say from here?

Comment: Also it might be useful to write $$S\subseteq \bigcup_{x\in \mathbb{Q}, n\in \mathbb{N}} \{ (x,y) \ : \ x^2 + y^2 = n^{-2}\} \cup \bigcup_{y\in \mathbb{Q}, n\in \mathbb{N}} \{ (x,y) \ : \ x^2 + y^2 = n^{-2}\}.$$ Now note that $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are countable and the square root has only two solutions.

Comment: @ ashk, do u mean, if for every rational $x$ we can have two solutions for $y$, and since the set of rational numbers are countable, the set $S$ is also countable.

Comment: Can we say here if for every rational $x$ we can have two solutions for $y$, say $y_{x_1}$ and $y_{x_2}$. Then the set $S$ can be expressed as $S=\cup_{x\in Q}\{(x,y_{x_1}),(x,y_{x_2})\}$, And since set of rationals are countable,  $S$ is countable

Comment: Yes, at most two solutions. See Severin's latest comment to finally conclude why $S$ is countable. Remember that countable union of countably many sets is countable.

Comment: We don't get two solutions exactly. Consider the two separate cases: $x=100$ and $n=1$ or $x=1$ and $n=1$. How many choices for $y$ do we have?

Answer (score 1):

$S$ is infinite. For example it contains all pairs $(0,1/n)$, $n\in \Bbb N$.

For every rational $x$ there are at most countably many $y$ such that $x^2+y^2=1/n^2$ for some integer $n$, thus the subset $S_1$ of $S$ consisting of pairs $(x,y)$ with rational $x$ is at most countable. Similarly the subset $S_2$ of $S$ consisting of pairs $(x,y)$ with rational $y$ is at most countable. Moreover $S=S_1\cup S_2$ by assumption, hence $S$ is at most countable.

Thus $S$ is countable.

Comment: No, the question only requires one of $x,y$ to be rational. (But $S$ is still countably infinite.)

Comment: Fixed. Thanks! ${}$